# Sending a meeting email with PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, outlook, gmail

I'm trying to send an ivitation mail for registered users with PHP, Laravel newest version 9.36

For this purpose I send an invite.ics file in the attachment. The MIME type is as follows: `'text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST'`.

Unfortunately the email is not recognized as a meeting but as an ordinary mail with attachment. Both in Outlook and Gmail client.

My question is, what do I have to set so that my mails are interpreted as meeting mails?
[image]

**attachment Email method:**

```
public function attachments(): array
{
     return [
            Attachment::fromData(function() {
                return $this->createIcs()->get();
            }, 'invite.ics')
            ->withMime('text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST')
     ];
}
```

**email headers method:**

```
public function headers(): Headers
{
    return new Headers(
        text: [
            'X-FE-Attachment-Name' => 'invite.ics',
        ],
    );
}
```

**creating ICS method:**

```
public function createIcs(): Calendar
{
    $registration = $this->registration;
    $location = $registration->location;

    return Calendar::create()
        ->appendProperty(
            TextProperty::create('CALSCALE', 'GREGORIAN'),
        )
        ->appendProperty(
            TextProperty::create('METHOD', 'REQUEST'),
        )
        ->event(
            Event::create()
                ->name($location->name)
                ->address($location->address)
                ->addressName($location->name)
                ->description('Welcome to the event: ' . $location->name)               
                ->organizer($registration->email, 'Acme Company')
                ->attendee($registration->email, $registration->email, ParticipationStatus::accepted(), requiresResponse: true)
                ->createdAt(now())
                ->startsAt(
                    new DateTime(
                        $location->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' ' . $location->schedule->start_time->format('H:i')
                    )
                )
                ->endsAt(
                    new DateTime(
                        $location->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' ' . $location->schedule->end_time->format('H:i')
                    )
                )
                ->withoutTimezone()
                ->status(EventStatus::confirmed())
                ->appendProperty(TextProperty::create('TRANSP', 'OPAQUE'))
    );
}
```

it generates an invite.ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Acme Company//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:63721bd7233ec
DTSTAMP:20221114T104335Z
SUMMARY:Event location name
DESCRIPTION:Welcome to the event: event name
LOCATION: event location
CLASS:PRIVATE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=My Company Roadshow:MAILTO:example@email.com
ATTENDEE;CN=my@email.com;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:my@email.com
DTSTART:20230118T070000
DTEND:20230118T150000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:The event is starting tomorrow!
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20230117T090000
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Email class is created using Laravel Symfony Mailer. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail

I only post the most important methods in the email class, where I might make a mistake.
If a code part for the understanding is missing I will of course provide it.

my header entries:
[image]

header entries from google meet:
[image]

Comment: Try to export any existing meeting request and compare with what you have sent.

Comment: I have tried that as well. I have sent myself an email from Google Meet. This is recognized without problems as meeting mail in Outlook or Gmail.

Then I tried to send the same .ics file I had received from Google Meet with my program as attachment. Unfortunately without success.

So the problem is not the .ics attachment. I guess it is the matching headers in the email.

Comment: Did you have a chance to compare the headers?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the screenshots from the mail headers.